# Why isn't jQuery validate working on my form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Can anyone tell me why the fields `yourTelephoneNumbers` and `yourEmailAddress` aren't being validated? Basically, I'm trying to design my form so that the user must enter either a phone number or email address.

**Console Log;**

Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/) bootstrap.js:2772:1

TypeError: validator is undefined

**Code in `<head>` tag;**

```
<head>
<title><?php echo COMPANY_NAME_DISPLAY; ?></title>
<!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- jQuery Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
<!-- Lightbox CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SITE_CSS; ?>lightbox.css">
<!-- Fancybox CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SITE_CSS; ?>fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SITE_CSS; ?>style.css">
<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script><!-- Form validation -->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script><!-- Form validation extension -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script><!-- Google Maps -->
<script src="<?php echo SITE_JAVASCRIPT; ?>fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script><!-- Fancybox -->
<script src="<?php echo SITE_JAVASCRIPT; ?>fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script><!-- Fancybox -->
<script src="<?php echo SITE_JAVASCRIPT; ?>jquery.form.min.js"></script><!-- AJAX form -->
</head>
```

[Actual development site](http://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/mlb/view_property.php?property_id=154) - Click the button labelled 'Make Enquiry'

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft8q9zcp/3/)

Comment: your jquery is breaking please check console.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - Please see my edit

Comment: its working there and no error in console. i received success message in console. { "status": "success", "message": "This is the success message." }

Comment: Please show us the ***relevant RENDERED*** HTML markup and JavaScript in your OP. You are only showing us the PHP for your `head` section. Do not rely on the broken jsFiddle to show your code, nor expect us to dig through your production site... neither of which will be very helpful to future readers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not show us the actual code in your OP, I can only comment on the various issues in your jsFiddle...

1. You have `id="makeEnquiry"` duplicated on the `<div>` and on the `<form>`.  You cannot duplicate any `id` and since the `.validate()` method is attached to this duplicated `id`, it would not work at all since it's using the first instance from the `div` and ignoring the instance from the `form`.
2. You **MUST** use the `name` attribute within the `rules` and `messages` objects inside of the `.validate()` method.  Your HTML markup was missing the `name` attribute entirely.  The jQuery Validate plugin will not work at all when the `name` attribute is missing.
3. You have an extra `});` in your jsFiddle causing a syntax error.
4. Your jsFiddle is missing a DOM ready event handler.
5. The `require_from_group` method needs [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js) included.  It is missing from your jsFiddle.
6. There were many bugs with the `require_from_group` method in previous versions of this plugin.  Your jsFiddle is using jQuery (1.7) and jQuery Validate (1.9), both of which are several years old by now.  Update to the latest versions.

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/8a3mwkw5/

Comment: @MichaelLB, you're welcome.  But #2 is also mandatory... this plugin will not work if the `name` attributes are missing.